# Dell iDRAC on dedicated NIC not accessible from the server itself

Tags: dell, drac

I have a Dell PE R720xd server with an enterprise iDRAC license.  I have iDRAC configured to use the dedicated NIC.

I can access iDRAC from anywhere except the actual server itself.  I could understand this happening if I were sharing iDRAC with one of the four onboard NICs, but I'm not -- it's the dedicated NIC.

Google searches for this were not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Just before I was going to send this question, I figured it out.  The problem turned out to be that I had enabled "OS to iDRAC Pass-Through" in the iDRAC network settings and configured the machine's IP address for that.  Once I disabled that setting, access was restored.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the iDRAC from the server itself, that is one of the explicit purposes of the iDRAC Service Module. See: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000178050/support-for-dell-emc-idrac-service-module

```
[root@r7525 ~]# ip a s
...SNIP...
6: idrac: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:2a:72:04:23:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.1.2/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global idrac
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...SNIP...
```

It will create a virtual interface on the operating system with IP address in the 169.254.0.0/16 range, typically 169.254.0.2, and the iDRAC will be at 169.254.0.1. You can then directly access the iDRAC from the host OS without having to go external to the server.

See https://grantcurell.github.io/Using%20the%20iDRAC%20Service%20Module/ for a walkthrough and screenshots.

Comment: I am having zabbix running on the same server monitor idrac with snmp.  Everything is working now... it was the "OS to iDRAC Pass-Through" option in the idrac settings that was causing it to not respond.

I do have the idrac service module installed on the server.  It hasn't created the interface you mentioned.  I have all of OMSA installed, including racadm.

Comment: Interesting - I added what it should look like above. You don't have that virtual interface?

Comment: The idrac interface is not there.  I have the dcism and dcism-osc packages installed from the deb repo.